# Fail endianess test when building project with CMAKE (macOS Catalina)

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a project that is written in C++ so we build it with CMAKE. I was working on it on a CentOS machine and everything was fine. However, now I've switched to macOS (I have the latest Catalina update) and first I cloned the repo from github, installed cmake and I tried to build it, but it fails due to the `ENDIANESS TEST` so the project doesn't finish building.[Here](https://github.com/basavyr/xrootd) is the repo that I'm trying to work on btw. I also use some additional flags, but that shouldn't be the issue. Any ideas how to fix this?

Here is the command that I use for trying to build:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -D ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/basavyr/Downloads/zlib-1.2.11/ -D OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include/ -D OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libssl.dylib -D OPENSSL/CRYPTO_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../tarball/xrootd ../
```

And here is the error I'm getting (ignore the other ones, those apparently do not affect the failing):

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:13 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0054 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Could NOT find systemd (missing: SYSTEMD_INCLUDE_DIRS SYSTEMD_LIBRARIES) 
-- Could NOT find Macaroons (missing: MACAROONS_INCLUDES MACAROONS_LIB) 
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
[I] Determining version from git
-- crc32c submodule update
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.2/share/cmake/Modules/TestBigEndian.cmake:50 (message):
  no suitable type found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  external/crc32c/CMakeLists.txt:67 (test_big_endian)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/basavyr/Pipeline/DevWorkspace/Github/xrootd/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/basavyr/Pipeline/DevWorkspace/Github/xrootd/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I've tried to search through those two files but I couldn't find anything useful to be honest. I've also tried to search this issue online but without any success.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Please provide the **full** CMake build log showing the compiler verification messages.

Comment: The project you are using says it is only supported on *MacOSX 10.6 and 10.7 compiled with gcc or clang*.  Catalina is at least 10.15.  That could be one issue